# Turn into Proposition logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, artificial-intelligence

I am new to logic. I am suffering to turn one of the following sentences from normal form into propositional logic. Paragraph as follows:

```
If Sahan has knowledge about computer hardware and proper training, he will be able to
assemble a computer. If Sahan hadn’t a proper training he will not have a job. But Sahan
will have a job. Therefore Sahan can assemble a computer.
```

I created propositions for each sentences, but my problem is in second sentences. According to the above para to create a propositions, `Sahan has knowledge about proper training` and  `Sahan hadn’t a proper training` are both or something different. I mean have I want to create two separate propositions for each sentences?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: "Sahan has knowledge about computer hardware and proper training" is the *conjunction* of two sentences : "Sahan has knowledge about computer hardware" **and** "Sahan has proper training".

Comment: What if Sahan has proper training but not knowledge about computer hardware ? This satisfies the conditions, but we cannot conclude that he can assemble a computer.

Comment: Thus, for the first sentences you need three prop variables : $K$ for "Sahan has knowledge about computer hardware", $T$ for "Sahan has proper training" and $A$ for "Sahan can (or : is able to) assemble a computer".

Comment: p -> Sahan has knowledge about computer hardware.

q -> Sahan has knowledge about proper training.

r  he will be able to assemble a computer.

s -> Sahan hadn’t a proper training

t -> Sahan will have a job.      Is this correct?

Comment: **NO** "Sahan has proper training." If we name it $q$, then "Sahan hadn’t a proper training" will be $\lnot q$.

Comment: I am turning into prepositional logic form for each sentences. Please be kind enough to check whether correct or not.                                                                  

 p ∧ q ⇒ r ,

 ¬ s ⇒ ¬ t ,

 t ,

 r .

Comment: I have turn above para into propositional logic. Please be good enough to make any improvement whether have any incorrect .                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                 
     ( p ∧ q  ⇒ r ) ∧ ¬ ( s ⇒  t) ∧ t ∧ r

Comment: However Thank you ever so much for your kindly help as well as share knowledge among us  Mr.Mauro ALLEGRANZA  and Mr. Peter. I think I gain something best

Comment: How did you go from $\neg s \Rightarrow \neg t$ to $\neg(s \Rightarrow t)$?  Why did you conjoin $r$?

Comment: In the above para I have a small doubt. Can someone could help me.                                                       `If Sahan hadn’t a proper training he will not have a job`. In this situation how can we change into propositions logic. I tried, but whether it is correct or not. Please be good enough to make any improvement whether have any incorrect of following logics .  `(¬ Q ∧ ¬ S)`  or `(¬ Q ⇒ ¬ S)`

Comment: Using $q$ for "Sahan had proper training" and $t$ for "Sahan will have a job", the formula for "If Sahan hadn’t a proper training he will not have a job" will be : $\lnot q \to \lnot t$.

Comment: Thanks for your cooperation

Answer (score 2):

$k$: has knowledge,
$t$: has proper training,
$a$: able to assemble a computer,
$j$: have a job

1. $k ∧ t → a$
2. $¬t → ¬j$
3. $j$

By applying [modus tollens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_tollens) to 2 and 3, we get $t$. However, we don't know the truth value of $k$. Therefore, the last sentence ($a$) can't be proved, since we can't apply [modus ponens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens) to 1.

Either you're missing a sentence (that the has knowledge about computer hardware) or the goal was to reach this conclusion.